# Load files one by one in Chrome Web developer's Coverage recording

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I press for recording files in Web developer's Coverage, the css and js files are actually loaded one by one, but it happens too fast. I want to be able to load files one by one in order to really see how each file impacts the website, like a step-through option when loading files. (It is otherwise too fast for me to see which css-file is causing a layout shift.)

Is it possible?